# Modal-dialog does not wish to close again

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, ckeditor

I use modals to load CKEditor in. It works, when I press a button the selected modal get's loaded. Then I press the next button to load the second modal. This also works fine, I can close it without a problem. But then, when I open the first one again, it does not want to close anymore... but I can't discover why. What is the problem?

```
<!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModalBesc" class="modal">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <span class="close">X</span>
              <h2>Beschrijving:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name='beschrijving' style='width: 400px;height:100px;'></textarea>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <h3>Klik op 'X' om te sluiten</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModalSpec" class="modal">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <span class="close">X</span>
              <h2>Specificaties:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name='specificaties' style='width: 400px;height:100px;'></textarea>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <h3>Klik op 'X' om te sluiten</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal Beschrijving-->
<button id="myBtnBesc" onclick="ModalBesc();">Open WYSIWYG</button>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal Specificaties-->
<button id="myBtnSpec" onclick="ModalSpec();">Open WYSIWYG</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function ModalBesc() {
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'beschrijving' );
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModalBesc'); 
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnBesc");
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            btn.onclick = function() {    
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        function ModalSpec() {
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'specificaties' );
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModalSpec'); 
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnSpec");
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            btn.onclick = function() {    
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Please help me out! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ModalBesc() {
  // CKEDITOR.replace( 'specificaties' );
  $("#myModalBesc").modal("show");
}

function ModalSpec() {
  // CKEDITOR.replace( 'specificaties' );
  $("#myModalSpec").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalBesc" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
      <h2>Beschrijving:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <br>
      <textarea name='beschrijving' style='width: 400px; height: 100px;'></textarea>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Klik op 'X' om te sluiten</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalSpec" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
      <h2>Specificaties:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <br>
      <textarea name='specificaties' style='width: 400px;height:100px;'></textarea>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Klik op 'X' om te sluiten</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal Beschrijving-->
<button id="myBtnBesc" onclick="ModalBesc(); return false;">Open WYSIWYG</button>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal Specificaties-->
<button id="myBtnSpec" onclick="ModalSpec(); return false;">Open WYSIWYG</button>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please see my answer for a runnable code snippet.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me out, it works perfectly right now!

Comment: No sorry, it still does not, they all open and close perfectly the first time, but after that, they don't wish to open anymore...

Comment: I can't seem to replicate that issue. What browser are you using?

Comment: When you notice the issue, open the developer console (hit F12) and let me know if you get any exceptions.